# How to create a logical code in python based on Excel file name?

Tags: python

I am automating manual tasks for a set of excel files...

1. Read the file from path.
2. Perform few calculation.
3. Modify and save the file in same Path.

**Challenge**

There are 2 sets of logic it needs to perform. For example, there are 1-10 files. Set 1. if File name is 1,2,4,7,9,10 it needs to perform one set of tasks and IF file name is 3,5,6,8 it needs to perform another set of task.

Comment: So what's the problem? Please show what you've written and explain where exactly you're stuck

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

for file_num in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]:
    file_name = 'file' + str(file_num) + '.xlsx'  # generate file name
    df = pd.read_excel(io=file_name)  # open df
    if file_num in [1,2,4,7,9,10]:
        # perform calculation 1 with df
    else:
        # perform calculation 2 with df
    df.to_excel('output_'+file_name)  # save df
```